# Minimum permissions required for an updatable query (Access Project)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In an Access Project (ADP), with a SQL backend, what are the minimum permissions required for Access to be able to update records returned from a view bound to a form, yet prevent a direct `SELECT` on the underlying table? For instance:

Table: `Table1`
Columns: `ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4`

View: `View1`

```
SELECT ID, Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 'Something'
```

As a database owner, or in the role `db_owner` (or roles `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`), the records can be updated via Access when bound to the view. However, if the user is not a member of these, the record is not updatable via Access. I granted `SELECT`, `UPDATE` to `View1` and denied `SELECT` to `Table1` and allowed `UPDATE` to `Table1` (in case having `UPDATE` on a view doesn't work). I also denied `UPDATE` to `Column1` as I don't want the users to update that column.

If I connect to the SQL Database (with SQL Server Management Studio) with these permissions set, I can update the records in the view, yet in Access I can't. Why is this? I don't know what queries Access is issuing to update a record to determined why it is failing.

**Edit:**

Still not figured out a way of finding out what permissions Access needs to do UPDATE without SELECT.. SQL Profiler did not show any obvious cause of the 'recordset not updatable' message.

Comment: I've never used ADPs, but one of the many complaints about them that I recall was that in certain circumstances, ADO bypasses your views (and your security settings therein) and tries to do update the underlying tables directly. I don't think the exact circumstances were the same as the ones you describe, but it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's possible for Access to update something it can't select.

You can attach [Sql Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx) to the server to see which queries Access is running.

Comment: It is retreiving the data, just via a view instead. Even with DENY SELECT on Table1, you can still see the data in Access, just not update it. Even GRANT SELECT on Table1 does not make it updatable.

Comment: Tried Sql Profiler but can't figure out how to limit it to queries that just run on a particular database (rather than all of them)

Comment: Under Trace properties > Events Selection tab > select show all columns. Now under column filters, you should see the database name. Enter the database name for the Like section and you should see traces only for that database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272730/sql-server-profiler-how-to-filter-trace-to-only-display-events-from-one-databas